# Word suggestion for items that can be labelled with a serial number and items that cannot be labelled with a serial number

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for a word (or a group of words) that describe items that can (or can’t) be labelled with a serial number/barcode. (I was thinking of “can serialable items” and “non-seriable items”, but I could not find *serialable* and *non-seriable* in dictionary.)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a little bit more context? What is this for? And can you give an example of an item that cannon be labelled with a serial number?

Comment: A example of a item that cannot be labelled with a serial number / bar code - capacitor. (Other examples are pen, pencils, spoon, fork, resistor, paper). A example of a item that can be labelled with a serial number / var code - Laptop. (Other examples are scanner, table, printer)

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/310034/adjective-for-having-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word 'serialized' can be used this way. It literally means arranged as a series or placed in a definite order. But products with serial numbers are arranged as a series and are placed in a definite order.

Some laws refer to products containing a serial number as "serialized" products. For example, California's [21628(b)](http://law.justia.com/codes/california/2010/bpc/21625-21647.html) says: "... [a] complete and reasonably accurate description of **serialized**
property, including, but not limited to, the following: serial number
and other identifying marks or symbols, owner-applied numbers, ..."

Comment: Hi David, may I know if I can consider the word 'non-serialized' for items that cannot be labelled?

Comment: "Non-serializable" and "non-serialized" are commonly used for the computer science meaning of "serialize" (convert into a stream of bytes). So I don't see why you can't use it for this one. You [certainly](http://www.4serialization.com/launch-a-pilot.html) wouldn't [be](http://support.insightdirect.com/help/inventory/nonserinv.htm) the [first](http://www.google.com/patents/about/10_283_357_Non_serialized_electronic_pro.html?id=REWeAAAAEBAJ) to [do](http://www.acq.osd.mil/dpap/dars/pgi/pgi_htm/245_2.htm) so.

Comment: Hi David, so, I can use the two word "Non-serializable" and "non-serialized" outside the computer science context cause my question is not related to computer science.

Comment: The [government does](http://www.acq.osd.mil/dpap/dars/pgi/pgi_htm/245_2.htm) so why not you.

Comment: Marked as answer

Answer (score 3):

You could use *trackable* for those that can be labelled, and *not trackable*, *nontrackable*, or *untrackable* for those that can.

From [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trackable):

> Adj. 1.trackable - capable of being traced or tracked;

Although now that I've typed *untrackable*, *untraceable* comes to mind, but I'm not sure it means quite what you want.

**EDIT**(side note: I've just noticed the site I linked lists *traceable* as an alternative)

**EDIT**
While responding to the comment below, I realized a very workable word for this is **indexed** for those itmes which are labelled/numbered (and **non-indexed** for those which are not).

**EDIT**:
Since you have many of each type of item, and are using the barcodes to differentiate between the barcoded items, you could use the terms [unique](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unique) and [generic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/generic).

Comment: for your information - you are on the right track to what I want. I still open for new word(s) suggestion.

Comment: @LarryMorries Is a count kept of all the non-indexed items?

Comment: all items will be counted as need to know how many items are in the storeroom.

Comment: @LarryMorries Well, that rules out *inventoried* vs *non-inventoried*.

Comment: there is no need to differentiate between the barcoded items but I appreciate those 2 words. I need most is the differentiate between barcoded items and non-barcoded items

Answer (score 2):

*Unlabelable.*

You say you are looking for a word to express that the object *cannot* be labeled with a serial number barcode. The issue seems to be not so much whether the object *should* be labeled, but just the practicality of putting a label on the object. So the most direct solutions would be negations of *labelable* or *barcodable*.

Out of the various combinations of *un-* and *non-* prefixes with *labelable* and *barcodable*, with or without the hyphen, only *unlabelable* shows up with any frequency in the *Google Ngram Viewer*.